# PowerShell - Query REST API with unsigned cert

Tags: powershell, ssl, visual-studio-code

I've recently switched from using the PowerShell ISE to using Visual Studio Code

When I run my PowerShell scripts from within VSC on my office PC (Win 10 64Bit), none of the REST connections that use Invoke-RestMethod over HTTPS will authenticate against servers that use an unsigned SSL cert. When run from within VSC on my home PC (also Win 10 64bit), all works OK.

I have a function in the PowerShell that uses System.Net.Security to deal with unsigned SSL certs, which works perfectly when I run the code as native PowerShell or from the ISE

Here is how I compensate for Invoke-RestMethod connecting via SSL sessions with self-signed certs:

```
if (-not("dummy" -as [type])) {
  add-type -TypeDefinition @"
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Security;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

  public static class Dummy {
    public static bool ReturnTrue(object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        return true;
    }

    public static RemoteCertificateValidationCallback GetDelegate() {
        return new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Dummy.ReturnTrue);
    }
  }
"@
}

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = [dummy]::GetDelegate()
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I also encode the username + password into a Base64 encoded hash that is the header for the Invoke-RestMethod call:

```
$pair = "${username}:${password}"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue }
```

So the complete call sequence is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://theserver.com/rest/api/whatever" -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

The server hosting the REST API, Confluence using Apache Tomcat, accepts the authentication when the PowerShell is run from within the ISE or executed directly, but throws back a response that the connection isn't authenticated if I try to run it from within VSC, but only on the PC at the office, not at home. I'm suspecting a security certificate issue or a policy interaction.

Comment: Can you share the function you mentioned? And what you mean by `it doesn't work from VSC`? Any errors?

Comment: Updated with code samples

Comment: What is the full error? Can you add it too?

Comment: Just updated the original post. I'm at home and it works via VSC locally! Will try in the office on Monday and post the response from Confluence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compared the branch of the version I had in the office with the prior one and found a tiny typo that was screwing the de-coding of the password without me noticing it.

It wasn't VSC after all; just me not being diligent.